# Autoionization of water

Tags: water, ph

Consider as solution of pure water at $\pu{25 ^\circ{}C}$ with a $K_{\mathrm{w}} =  10^{-14}$.

If we are to add an acid to the mix we would observe an increase in hydronium and an equal decrease in hydroxide content.

Yet, I fail to see how the hydroxide ion concentration can decrease with an increase in hydronium concentration.

Lets add $\ce{HCl}$ to our solution: $$\ce{HCl + H2O -> Cl- + H3O+}$$
Concentration $[\ce{H3O+}]$ increases,  concentration $[\ce{OH-}]$ decreases in order to fulfill the $K_{\mathrm{w}}$ constant of $10^{-14}$.

Through what reaction exactly then will the hydroxide content decrease (by turning into water I assume)? Where does $\ce{OH-}$ gets an $\ce{H+}$ from? Not from $\ce{H3O+}$, I assume seeing that every molecule of a strong acid is said to turn into an hydronium ion 1:1.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: H+ is in acidobasic reaction context just convenience for H3O+ ( which is exactly convenience for H3O+ . n H2O ). As H+ is nothing else but a proton/deuteron, which creates locally so strong electrostatic field which does not allow its free existence in condensed phases.

Comment: @Lars To facilitate rendering chemical equations _in the body_ of a question, answer, or comment, ChemSE offers you to use mathJax and mhchem syntax.  Which I applied to the current form of your question.  You may familiarize yourself with the underlying rules e.g., [here](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).  Because it is not understood by all internet browsers, you _should not_ use this peculiar syntax in the title of a question.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thanks, message deleted.

Comment: Note that the kinetic rate of $\ce{H3O+ + OH-  -> 2 H2O}$ is $\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{OH-}]}{\mathrm{d}t}=k \cdot [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}]$ and it is one of the fastest ever chemical reactions, controlled by diffusion.

Comment: To answer your question, yes the $\ce{H+}$ cations that react with the $\ce{OH-}$ anions come from the acid. Remember that in pure water the $\ce{OH-}$ anion concentration is only $1\times 10^{-7}$ so if you have a 0.1 molar acid solution then a minuscule fraction of the acid is consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a numerical example will help you. Let's start from pure water, with the following concentrations :$\ce{[H+] = [OH-] = 10^{-7} M}$. Now we will suppose you add $\ce{10^{-7}} mol$ $\ce{HCl}$ in one liter of this water. Suddenly, the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ should double. This is not possible in the long run. A part $a$ of these supplementary $\ce{H+}$ ions must react with the same amount $a$ of the $\ce{OH-}$ ions to form water. The final molar concentrations of both ions are given by  : $$\ce{[H+] = 2.000·10^{-7}} - a$$  $$\ce{[OH-] = 1.000·10^{-7} } - a$$   This amount $a$ may be obtained by solving the equation : $$\ce{ (2.000·10^{-7}} - a)\ce{(1.000 10^{-7}} - a)= 1.000·10^{-14}$$ The solution is : $a = 0.382·10^{-7} mol/L$. So about $38.2$% of the initial $\ce{OH-}$ ions have been destroyed by the addition of the new acidic ions. And the numerical values of the final concentrations are $$\ce{[H+] = 2.00·10^{-7}}- a = 1.618·10^{-7} mol/L$$$$\ce{[OH-] = 1.00 10^{-7} } - a = 0.618· 10^{-7} mol/L$$ And of course : $\ce{[Cl-] = 1.000·10^{-7}$ $ mol/L}$. If you want you may check the product of the two final concentrations $\ce{[H+]}$ and $\ce{[OH-]}$. It is equal to ${1.000·10^{-14} mol^2L^{-2}}$.